# Android adapter to deal with a key and a value

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I want to populate a spinner in my android application, Is there a default adapter that can deal with a  key and a value? Because the ArrayAdapter only stores one value per item?

I want my spinner to have the following:

1    dog
2    cat
3    mouse

But it must only display the value, but when I submit my input I want to be able to get the id / key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pojo class

```
public class SpinnerUtils {
     public SpinnerUtils(String spinnerText, int value) {
         this.spinnerText = spinnerText;
         this.value = value;
     }

     public String getSpinnerText() {
         return spinnerText;
     }

     public int getValue() {
         return value;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return spinnerText;
     }

     String spinnerText;
     int value;
 }
```

Then

```
 SpinnerUtils items[]=new SpinnerUtils[array.length()];
    items[i] = new SpinnerUtils(c.getString("name"), c.getInt("id"));   

    for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++) {

items[i] = new SpinnerUtils(c.getString("name"), c.getInt("id"));                       
                }


         ArrayAdapter<SpinnerUtils> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerUtils>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where s is your spinner.
To retrieve the id:

```
 SpinnerUtils d = items[position];
             int   standard = d.getValue();
```

Create the above 2 lines within the `setOnItemSelectedListener` of the spinner to get the id.I have given you a rough idea.Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayAdapter can contain one value, true, but this value can be an anything ;)

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>()
new ArrayAdapter<MyObject>()
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>()
```

Comment: I see, so a simple object in there will do.